# Why doesn't IntelliJ find my class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ]

But project compiles successfully. And method which uses `TemplatesStatisticsDTO` works right.
Those red lines are annoying me.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016
Licensed to <...>
Subscription is active until July 5, 2017
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_91-b15 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: just clean and build. see what happens?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne ty. You can rewrite as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be because of something went wrong with synchronizing the build state with editor.

try

Clean and Build again. :))